# Console.log shows hidden object info

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I do `console.log(someobject)`, I see some `__proto__` object things inside my object, which contain a huge amount of data in them.

If I have a lot properties on my objects (properties that are also objects), I can easily get hundreds of **protos**. Anyway does this affect performance in any way? Should I use arrays instead?

Comment: arrays and objects are totally two different things. use what you need...

Comment: Arrays also inherit from `Object`, so you don't gain anything in this regard. Basically everything is an object in JavaScript (primitive types are converted to objects when you access their methods). That's JavaScript. Which data structure to use depends on your data...

Comment: well I'm only using objects because I can treat them like arrays with keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just part of JavaScript's internal prototype chain. Whenever a new object is created, its `__proto__` property is set to its "parent" object's `prototype` property. To answer your question, it has no impact on performance that you can control directly, so don't worry about it.

If you want to read more about it, check out MDN, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Proto

Answer (score 1):

Familiarize yourself with the prototypical inheritance JavaScript uses. See, e.g., [here at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

In a nutshell: Objects in JavaScript are not created by instantiating classes, but creating an object that is like another object (the prototype). So every object has a pointer to its prototype.

If a method or attribute of an object is required at some point in the code, the compiler checks, whether the object posseses such a property itself (comp. [hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)). If not, it takes a look at the respective prototype object. If the property can not be found there it looks at the prototype of the prototype an so forth. This is done all the way up to `Object`, which is the base prototype in JavaScript. The chain of prototypes is also called `prototype chain`.

As this is an inherent feature of the language you can not circumvent it anyways and thus it wont have any impact on your specific site's performance.

Answer (score 1):

This may slow down the `console.log` calls, but not not your application in production mode.
Anyway the [__proto__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Proto) property of `Object`objects is a non-standard and deprecated Mozilla extension, it is going to be removed someday so don't worry about it (the standard `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)` method can already bu used instead of `obj.__proto__`).